# ubuntu 18.04 libre base will not load says jre is corrupt

Tags: 18.04

This is my current java
 java -version
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l
ibm-java80-jre-x86_64 80 /usr/lib/jvm/ibm-java80-jre-x86_64 
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 1101 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 1081 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 
java-8-oracle 1081 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Comment: Please add output of `update-java-alternatives -l` to the question.

Comment: ibm-java80-jre-x86_64          80         /usr/lib/jvm/ibm-java80-jre-x86_64
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1101       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
java-8-oracle                  1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: Then try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall openjdk-8-jre-headless`.

Comment: still receive the same message corrupt JRE.